# Seeking algorithms for DEM generation?

Tags: dem, remote-sensing, algorithm, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, model

What are the different algorithms employed for the generation of a Digital elevation model from images captured using an unmanned aerial vehicle ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drone aerial imagery to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202576/drone-aerial-imagery-to-qgis)

Comment: This post is asking about generating DEM. The post you link is related to image not being georeferenced once brought into QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this post [How can i create a Digital Elevation Model from satellite Images?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_i_create_a_Digital_Elevation_Model_from_satellite_Images)

> If you have stereo pair of satellite images or overlapping aerial photographs or even UAV acquired imagery, you can use a standard GIS software to generate a DEM based on the principles of Photogrammetry. There are open source as well as commercially available softwares which can do the job. ERDAS Imagine LPS Suite, ENVI, ArcGIS, PCI Geomatica, NASA's Ames Stereo Pipeline, Pix4D, Drone2Map, etc. are some of the names in the business. The internet has made our lives much easier nowadays. It might be a good idea to google for 'dem generation with stereo' and you will get thousands of results.
>   Hope this gives you some hint.

http://www.crisp.nus.edu.sg/~research/dem/dem.htm
https://ti.arc.nasa.gov/tech/asr/groups/intelligent-robotics/ngt/stereo/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDnWYh36d3c
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoTZj77F08M
https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/