# Seeking code sample or pointer showing how to calculate Corner Coordinates of JPG file based on EXIF GPS data?

Tags: gdal, gps, georeferencing, jpg, exif

This is a follow up to this question:
[Using GDAL to extract Corner Coordinates based on a jpg file's GPS EXIF data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308797/using-gdal-to-extract-corner-coordinates-based-on-a-jpg-files-gps-exif-data)

Per the answer I received to the above question, `gdal_merge` cannot merge JPG images that a are produced my most Drone manufacturers. The reason is that usually, Drone images do not include Corner Coordinates. All the Drone image Merging applications rely upon and use the rich set of EXIF GPS coordinates inside Drone JPG images (includes altitude and camera angles).

Here is an example of drone image set that `gdal_merge` cannot merge:
https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/odm_data_aukerman/tree/master/images

Is there any batch command line tool or code sample that can help to calculate and add Corner Coordinates to JPG images based on the rich set of EXIF GPS data that exists in Drone JPG images?

I am building a batch process and I **cannot use GUI interactive tools like QGIS**. I can create or call code in any language (Pathon, Node etc..) or preferably I can call another command line tool.

Here is an example of GPS EXIF data that `gdalinfo` provides. Note the  zero Corner Coordinates.

```
Driver: JPEG/JPEG JFIF
Files: 0.JPG
Size is 4896, 3672
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  EXIF_BrightnessValue=(7.53672)
  EXIF_ColorSpace=1
  EXIF_ComponentsConfiguration=0x01 0x02 0x03 0x00
  EXIF_CompressedBitsPerPixel=(3)
  EXIF_Contrast=0
  EXIF_CustomRendered=0
  EXIF_DateTime=2016:06:29 10:47:04
  EXIF_DateTimeDigitized=2016:06:29 10:47:04
  EXIF_DateTimeOriginal=2016:06:29 10:47:04
  EXIF_DigitalZoomRatio=(1)
  EXIF_ExifVersion=0230
  EXIF_ExposureBiasValue=(0)
  EXIF_ExposureMode=0
  EXIF_ExposureProgram=2
  EXIF_ExposureTime=(0.004)
  EXIF_FileSource=0x03
  EXIF_Flash=16
  EXIF_FlashpixVersion=0100
  EXIF_FNumber=(3.3)
  EXIF_FocalLength=(4.45)
  EXIF_GPSAltitude=(346.315)
  EXIF_GPSLatitude=(41) (18) (13.7576)
  EXIF_GPSLatitudeRef=N
  EXIF_GPSLongitude=(81) (45) (1.6792)
  EXIF_GPSLongitudeRef=W
  EXIF_ImageDescription=                               
  EXIF_Interoperability_Index=R98
  EXIF_Interoperability_Version=0x30 0x31 0x30 0x30
  EXIF_ISOSpeedRatings=100
  EXIF_LensSpecification=(4.45) (44.5) (3.3) (5.9)
  EXIF_LightSource=0
  EXIF_Make=SONY
  EXIF_MakerNote=SONY DSC 
  EXIF_MaxApertureValue=(3.44531)
  EXIF_MeteringMode=5
  EXIF_Model=DSC-WX220
  EXIF_PixelXDimension=4896
  EXIF_PixelYDimension=3672
  EXIF_RecommendedExposureIndex=100
  EXIF_ResolutionUnit=2
  EXIF_Saturation=0
  EXIF_SceneCaptureType=0
  EXIF_SceneType=0x01
  EXIF_SensitivityType=2
  EXIF_Sharpness=0
  EXIF_Software=eBee
  EXIF_UserComment=
  EXIF_WhiteBalance=0
  EXIF_XResolution=(350)
  EXIF_YCbCrPositioning=2
  EXIF_YResolution=(350)
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 3672.0)
Upper Right ( 4896.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 4896.0, 3672.0)
Center      ( 2448.0, 1836.0)
Band 1 Block=4896x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 2448x1836, 1224x918, 612x459, 160x120
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
Band 2 Block=4896x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 2448x1836, 1224x918, 612x459, 160x120
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
Band 3 Block=4896x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 2448x1836, 1224x918, 612x459, 160x120
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG
```

---

GUI applications like QGIS can perfectly do this and there are many youtube vidoes (and paid courses) showing how to do that.

However, this question is looking for a sample code or command line application that I can call in my batch application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drone aerial imagery to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202576/drone-aerial-imagery-to-qgis)

Comment: @Mat, it is not a duplicate. This question is seeking a code sample - and it seems that the answer is there is no such thing.

Comment: There is code in https://github.com/verticalphotoplacer/VerticalPhotoPlacer that could be used for study. It looks to be some work to reimpliment in a straight up gdal framework. https://github.com/verticalphotoplacer/VerticalPhotoPlacer/blob/master/model/uav_georeference.py has the corner coordinate calc for upper left pixel, if all you need is placement and no lens correction.

Answer (score 2):

Dont think its possible directly.

Usual process for this task is:

- align/match set of photos,
- create cloud of points (reconstruction of 3D scene),
- creation of ortophoto (which is composit of rectified input photos), georeferencig ortophoto.

To produce ortophoto from set of images you need to use structure from motion software. Some software suggestions are listed Here: [Drone aerial imagery to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202576/drone-aerial-imagery-to-qgis).
I strongly suggest you read answers and comments on this post!

There are couple of open source projects if you want to use the code: [Alice vision](https://alicevision.github.io/), [PPT](http://opensourcephotogrammetry.blogspot.com/2010/09/python-photogrammetry-toolbox.html), [OpenSfm](https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM), [Open Drone Map](https://www.opendronemap.org/) ...