# How can I display an image on QGIS from a DJI drone using python?

Tags: qgis, gdal, pyqgis-3, dji

I have a few images from a DJI drone and I can get all of the information from the image exifread.   I am trying to get an image to be displayed in the correct location on a QGIS map.  Is there an example of how to use this data to get the image to show correctly on a QGIS map?

I have tried the GDAL and nothing happens yet.

https://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html

```
Elements
drone-dji:AbsoluteAltitude= 258.91
drone-dji:RelativeAltitude= 60.9
drone-dji:GimbalRollDegree= 0.0
drone-dji:GimbalYawDegree= -148.3
drone-dji:GimbalPitchDegree= -90.0
drone-dji:FlightRollDegree= -2.8
drone-dji:FlightYawDegree= 179.4
drone-dji:FlightPitchDegree= -7.3

Exif Data
Key: Image ImageDescription  value  DCIM\100MEDIA\DJI_0002.JPG
Key: Image Make  value  DJI
Key: Image Model  value  FC550
Key: Image Orientation  value  Horizontal (normal)
Key: Image XResolution  value  72
Key: Image YResolution  value  72
Key: Image ResolutionUnit  value  Pixels/Inch
Key: Image Software  value  v01.29.5379
Key: Image DateTime  value  2019:04:25 10:50:33
Key: Image YCbCrPositioning  value  Centered
Key: Image ExifOffset  value  182
Key: GPS GPSVersionID  value  [0, 0, 0, 0]
Key: GPS GPSLatitudeRef  value  N
Key: GPS GPSLatitude  value  [42, 31, 524857/10000]
Key: GPS GPSLongitudeRef  value  W
Key: GPS GPSLongitude  value  [83, 6, 552361/10000]
Key: GPS GPSAltitudeRef  value  0
Key: GPS GPSAltitude  value  258907/1000
Key: Image GPSInfo  value  710
Key: Image XPComment  value  [48, 0, 46, 0, 57, 0, 46, 0, 49, 0, 57, 0, 57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... ]
Key: Image XPKeywords  value  [78, 0, 45, 0, 65, 0, 83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Key: Thumbnail Compression  value  JPEG (old-style)
Key: Thumbnail XResolution  value  72
Key: Thumbnail YResolution  value  72
Key: Thumbnail ResolutionUnit  value  Pixels/Inch
Key: Thumbnail JPEGInterchangeFormat  value  41972
Key: Thumbnail JPEGInterchangeFormatLength  value  8148
Key: EXIF ExposureTime  value  521/500000
Key: EXIF FNumber  value  11/5
Key: EXIF ExposureProgram  value  Program Normal
Key: EXIF ISOSpeedRatings  value  110
Key: EXIF ExifVersion  value  0230
Key: EXIF DateTimeOriginal  value  2019:04:25 10:50:33
Key: EXIF DateTimeDigitized  value  2019:04:25 10:50:33
Key: EXIF ComponentsConfiguration  value  CrCbY
Key: EXIF CompressedBitsPerPixel  value  6343987/1990656
Key: EXIF ShutterSpeedValue  value  -9906/-1000
Key: EXIF ApertureValue  value  227/100
Key: EXIF ExposureBiasValue  value  0
Key: EXIF MaxApertureValue  value  17/10
Key: EXIF SubjectDistance  value  0
Key: EXIF MeteringMode  value  Spot
Key: EXIF LightSource  value  Unknown
Key: EXIF Flash  value  No flash function
Key: EXIF FocalLength  value  15
Key: EXIF FlashPixVersion  value  0010
Key: EXIF ColorSpace  value  sRGB
Key: EXIF ExifImageWidth  value  4608
Key: EXIF ExifImageLength  value  3456
Key: Interoperability InteroperabilityIndex  value  R98
Key: Interoperability InteroperabilityVersion  value  [48, 49, 48, 48]
Key: EXIF InteroperabilityOffset  value  680
Key: EXIF ExposureIndex  value  0/0
Key: EXIF FileSource  value  Digital Camera
Key: EXIF SceneType  value  0
Key: EXIF CustomRendered  value  Normal
Key: EXIF ExposureMode  value  Auto Exposure
Key: EXIF WhiteBalance  value  Auto
Key: EXIF DigitalZoomRatio  value  0/0
Key: EXIF FocalLengthIn35mmFilm  value  30
Key: EXIF SceneCaptureType  value  Standard
Key: EXIF GainControl  value  None
Key: EXIF Contrast  value  Normal
Key: EXIF Saturation  value  Normal
Key: EXIF Sharpness  value  Normal
Key: EXIF DeviceSettingDescription  value  [0, 0, 0, 0]
Key: EXIF SubjectDistanceRange  value  0
Key: EXIF LensMake  value  UnKnown
Key: EXIF LensModel  value  DJI MFT 15mm F1.7 ASPH
PS C:\Users\Cary\Documents\Programming\Python\RailProfile>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

1. Processing Tool: Import geotagged photos

or

2. Plugin: ImportPhotos

[image: Processing Tool: Import geotagged photos]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That worked well for adding the marker in the correct position.   Then when I look at the marker info it displays the file location.   I am trying to display the actual photo on the map.

Comment: If you use QGIS 3.6, then you can change the marker type to raster image marker and set it to the source of the images with the datadefinde override of the filepath. I add an image how to proceed to the above solution.

Comment: That worked fantastic!   Thanks a bunch.

Comment: See this link for a more detailed discussion:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202576/drone-aerial-imagery-to-qgis/418353#418353

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this Vertical Photo Placer plugin helps [github link](https://github.com/verticalphotoplacer/VerticalPhotoPlacer). It can read the GPS and camera metadata to perform simple geo-referencing for vertical drone photos, and place them on map.

Comment: @mdc I just looked at the link for VerticalPhotoPlacer.  I will try the QGIS plugin with a few recent images. That does look interesting.  Does it use the gimbal angle and roll pitch yaw to place the image also?

Comment: @CaryH the plugin uses flight yaw angle and some camera's parameters to calculate rotation and stretching of the photo, but only designed for vertical photos.